# Rasa - ClientResponseError: 404, Requested URL /webhook not found

Tags: chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I'm using rasa 2.8.0 with docker. I want to run a form "name_form" after the intent greet but I'm getting following error:

> **DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  -** Predicted next action 'name_form' with confidence 1.00.
> **DEBUG    rasa.core.actions.forms**  - Activated the form 'name_form'.
> **DEBUG    rasa.core.actions.forms**  - No pre-filled required slots to validate.
> **DEBUG    rasa.core.actions.forms**  - Validating user input 'UserUttered(text: Hey, intent: greet, use_text_for_featurization: False)'.
> **DEBUG    rasa.core.actions.forms**  - Validating extracted slots: {}
> **DEBUG    rasa.core.actions.action  -** Calling action endpoint to run action 'validate_name_form'.
> **ERROR    rasa.core.processor  -** Encountered an exception while running action 'name_form'.Bot will continue, but the actions events are lost. Please check the logs of your action server for more information.
> **Traceback (most recent call last):**
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasa/core/actions/action.py", line 686, in run
> json=json_body, method="post", timeout=DEFAULT_REQUEST_TIMEOUT
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasa/utils/endpoints.py", line 155, in request
> response.status, response.reason, await response.content.read()
> rasa.utils.endpoints.ClientResponseError: 404, Not Found, body='b'\xe2\x9a\xa0\xef\xb8\x8f 404 \xe2\x80\x94 Not Found\n\n        html { font-family: sans-serif }\n        h2 { color: #888; }\n        .tb-wrapper p { margin: 0 }\n        .frame-border { margin: 1rem }\n        .frame-line > * { padding: 0.3rem 0.6rem }\n        .frame-line { margin-bottom: 0.3rem }\n        .frame-code { font-size: 16px; padding-left: 4ch }\n        .tb-wrapper { border: 1px solid #eee }\n        .tb-header { background: #eee; padding: 0.3rem; font-weight: bold }\n        .frame-descriptor { background: #e2eafb; font-size: 14px }\n    \n
>
> Requested URL /webhook not found\n''

Following is in my endpoints.yml:

action_endpoint:
url: "http://localhost:5005/webhook"

in the frontend script.js, the url is :

```
const rasa_server_url = "http://localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook";
```

Please anyone can tell me what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you launch the action server, what port is it on? I believe the default is 5055 rather than 5005, so if that's the port the action server is on you'll want to make sure your endpoint is looking in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

When I am running action server using docker, I have to give action_server:5055/webhook in endpoints.yml instead of localhost:5055/webhook.